# Filtering Datagrid Binded to DataTable WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am trying to create a filtering system for a DataGrid in WPF just as in the link -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

[image]

I am using the same library that they are using but the thing is I need to bind my DataGrid to a datatable...

And there is where the error is.. the filter library works perfectly as long as the ItemSource is a LIST but stops to work when the ItemSource is a DataTable...

Any Alternatives or Suggestions??? Working Examples appreciated..

**I am using AutoColumnGeneration=True since i don't know how many column do i need to populate**

Comment: Have you tried binding the ItemSource to a CollectionViewSource taken from the DataTable?

Comment: Actually the thing is that my AutoColumnGeneration = TRUE..
as i don't know the exact number of columns that i need to populate..

Now any suggestions

Comment: I had to do this before.  But the effort had a very short fuse on it so I created a CollectionViewSource from the rows and used a bespoke Value Converter.  It worked perfectly, but I'm sure there's better ways.  Also in the first instance you cannot use code that's wrapped around strongly typed collections with a data table because a data table uses boxed arrays!

Comment: Can i have a working sample of the same??

Comment: If nobody else comes along with something, I can check my stuff and find it, but are you happy to accept something that's a quick solution?

Comment: yes dude its kind of urgent...    no solution has worked for me till now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each DataRow in a table contains a flat Array of objects whose type is accessible only by extracting it from the DataColumns array.  Since everything in the Array is boxed, a library that relies upon a strongly typed collection, like List of T will not be compatible.  That should explain why it's not working.

You wrote that it's urgent and  I had to do the same type of thing once in a project with a very short fuse and I'll outline my approach.  This answer is for *URGENT* cases only.

Here's a ViewModel...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CollectionView MyCollectionView { get; set; }
    public ViewModel(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        MyCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataTable.Rows) as CollectionView;
        if (MyCollectionView != null)
        {
            MyCollectionView.Filter = o => (o as DataRow).ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("2");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The Constructor takes a DataTable and uses the Rows as the binding source to a CollectionView.  Since the CollectionView has built-in filtering and sorting properties, it's a great tool to use as a binding source.  Also as shown, the Constructor adds a filter for an example to help get you started.

To present the data to the user, consider the following Xaml...

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionView}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"    Binding="{Binding ., Converter=
                       {db:DbConverter}, ConverterParameter=PersonName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address"    Binding="{Binding ., Converter=
                        {db:DbConverter}, ConverterParameter=PersonAddress}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This is a DataGrid whose ItemsSource is bound to the CollectionView that was declared and assigned in the ViewModel.  Each column of data is passed through a converter along with a parameter which tells the converter what it needs to do.

To cap everything off, here's the converter...

```
public class DbConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, int> ParameterToColumnMapping;
    static DbConverter()
    {
        ParameterToColumnMapping = new Dictionary<object, int>
            {
                {"PersonName", 0}, {"PersonAddress", 1}
            };
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataRow dr = value as DataRow;
        if (dr != null)
        {
            if (ParameterToColumnMapping.ContainsKey(parameter))
            {
                return dr.ItemArray[ParameterToColumnMapping[parameter]];
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

That should get you back on track with filtering and presenting when you have a DataTable and an urgent situation.  All in the coding takes about an hour.  Note also that mine binds to the *Rows*, but you can also bind to the *DefaultView* if needs be.