# How to bind WPF datagrid to a list of dynamic items

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working with VS2015 and WPF on a view in which i have a dropdownlist with a list of viewnames (which are in my MySQL database) for selection of one view for data search and a datagrid for displaying the resulting data from the search.

Normally we are working with Entity Framework and using List with the type of a certain entity (table or view) as source for the datagrids.

But in that case we have to make a dynamic search.

So i created a connection to our MySQL database in code-behind and read all data from the selected view into a DataTable object which is bound to the datagrid by MVVM.

Unfortunately the datagrid needs a filter in which the users can enter parameters for filtering the results in the datagrid.

Without the filter my datatable-solution works fine, but with the filter it causes a bug.

So i tried to make - according to the lists of entity we are using normally - a list of dynamic objects out of the datatable from the search according to this post:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/generating-a-class-dynamically-from-types-that-are-fetched-at-runtime

The good news is: I have no filter bug anymore.

The bad news is: I see a lot of black lines in the datagrid and no data.

What have i done wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code. First the field and property for the datagrid's source:

```
private List<dynamic> viewDataItemsList = new List<dynamic>();
public List<dynamic> ViewDataItemsList
{
    get { return viewDataItemsList; }
    set
    {
        viewDataItemsList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ViewDataItemsList");
    }
}
```

Then the code i'm using for the search:

```
public void ReadDataFromSelectedView(string viewName)
{
    // Creates MySQL-connection without EntityFramework and reads data from the selected view
    var db = new paragraph16Entities();
    string connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + viewName;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dataTable);
    var cb = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    conn.Close();
    ViewData = dataTable;

    // Tries to create a list of dynamic objects a source for the datagrid
    List<dynamic> itemsList = new List<dynamic>();
    DynamicEntity viewDataItem;
    dynamic item;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            values.Add(column.ColumnName, row[column.ColumnName]);
        }
        viewDataItem = new DynamicEntity(values);
        item = viewDataItem;
        itemsList.Add(item);
    }
    ViewDataItemsList = itemsList;
    testEvaluationView.grdTestData.Items.Refresh();
}
```

This is the XAML-defintion of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdTestData"
          Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          filter:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
          filter:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
          filter:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible="True"
          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl},ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ViewDataItemsList, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Margin="5"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          IsReadOnly="True">
</DataGrid>
```

And finally the class DynamicEntity:

```
public class DynamicEntity : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> _values;

    public DynamicEntity(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = _values[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that the data grid displays the records if you remove the filters from the xaml?

Comment: Hello Raviraj. When i use the datatable i get from the search and the grid don't use the filter (which is defined in the XAML) i can see the records. But we need the filter in the datagrid and datatable as source instead of a collection of entities causes a bug.

Comment: Here this will help you, already answered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261611/filtering-datagrid-binded-to-datatable-wpf